# Neo4j - Variable length greater 11 runs forever and query never returns

Tags: neo4j, cypher, common-table-expression

I'm lost and tried everything I can think of. Maybe you can help me.

I'm trying to find all dependencies for a given software package. In this special case I'm working with the Node.js / JavaScript ecosystem and scraped the whole npm registry. My data model is simple, I've got packages and a package can have multiple versions.

In my database I have 113.339.030 dependency relationships and 19.753.269 versions.

My whole code works fine until I found a package that has so many dependencies (direct and transitive) that all my queries break down. It's called `react-scripts`. Here you can see the package information.

https://registry.npmjs.org/react-scripts

One visualizer never finishes

https://npm.anvaka.com/#/view/2d/react-scripts

and another one creates a dependency graph so big it's hard to analyze.

https://npmgraph.js.org/?q=react-scripts

At first I tried PostgreSQL with recursive common table expression.

```sql
with recursive cte as (
    select
        child_id
    from
        dependencies
    where
        dependencies.parent_id = 16674850
    union
    select
        dependencies.child_id
    from
        cte
    left join dependencies on
        cte.child_id = dependencies.parent_id 
    where
        cte.child_id is not null
)
select * from cte;
```

That returns 1.726 elements which seems to be OK. https://deps.dev/npm/react-scripts/4.0.3/dependencies returns 1.445 dependencies.

However I'd like to get the path to the nodes and that doesn't work well with PostgreSQL and `UNION`. You'd have to use `UNION ALL` but the query will be much more complicated and slower. That's why I thought I'd give Neo4j a chance.

My nodes have the properties

- `version_id`: integer
- `name`: string
- `version`: string

I'm starting with what I thought would be a simple query but it's already failing.
Start with version that has `version_id` `16674850` and give me all its dependencies.

```
MATCH p = (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})-[:DEPENDS_ON*..11]->(b:Version)
return DISTINCT b;
```

I have an index on `version_id`.

```
CREATE INDEX FOR (version:Version) ON (version.version_id)
```

That works until I set the depth to variable length to or greater `12`.

[image: plan]

Then the query runs forever. Here is the query plan.

[image: greater 12]

Neo4j runs inside Docker. I've increased some memory settings.

```
- NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_initial__size=2G
- NEO4J_dbms_memory_heap_max__size=2G
- NEO4J_dbms_memory_pagecache_size=1G
```

Any ideas? I'm really lost right now and don't want to give up on my "software dependency analysis graph".
I spent the last 6 weeks on this problem.
Thank you very much!

---

Edit 28/09/2021

I uploaded a sample data set. Here are the links

- https://s3.amazonaws.com/blog.spolytics.com/versions.csv (737.1 MB)
- https://s3.amazonaws.com/blog.spolytics.com/dependencies.csv (1.7 GB)

Here is the script to import the data.

```
neo4j-admin import \
    --database=deps \
    --skip-bad-relationships \
    --id-type=INTEGER \
    --nodes=Version=import/versions.csv \
    --relationships=DEPENDS_ON=import/dependencies.csv
```

That might help to do some experiments on your side and to reproduce my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble here is that Cypher is interested in finding all possible path that match a pattern. That can make it problematic for cases when you just want distinct reachable nodes, where you really don't care about expanding to every distinct path, but just finding nodes and ignoring any alternate paths leading to nodes already visited.

Also, the planner is making a bad choice with that cartesian product plan, that can make the problem worse.

I'd recommend using APOC Procedures for this, as there are procs that are optimized to expanding to distinct nodes and ignoring paths to those already visited. `apoc.path.subgraphNodes()` is the procedure.

Here's an example of use:

```
MATCH (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(a, {relationshipFilter:'DEPENDS_ON>', labelFilter:'>Version', maxLevel:11}) YIELD node as b
RETURN b
```

The arrow in the relationship filter indicates direction, and since it's pointing right it refers to traversing outgoing relationships. If we were interested in traversing incoming relationships instead, we would have the arrow at the start of the relationship name, pointing to the left.

For the label filter, the prefixed `>` means the label is an end label, meaning that we are only interested in returning the nodes of that given label.

You can remove the `maxLevel` config property if you want it to be an unbounded expansion.

More options and details here:

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/expand-subgraph-nodes/

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a large dataset like yours, but I think you could bring the number of paths down by filtering the b nodes. Does this work , as a start?

```
MATCH p = (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})-[:DEPENDS_ON*..11]->(b:Version)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->())
UNWIND nodes(p) AS node
return COUNT(DISTINCT node)
```

To check if you can return longer paths, you could do

```
MATCH p = (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})-[:DEPENDS_ON*..12]->(b:Version)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->())
RETURN count(p)
```

Now if that works, I would do :

```
MATCH p = (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})-[:DEPENDS_ON*..12]->(b:Version)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->())
RETURN p LIMIT 10
```

to see whether the paths are correct.

Sometimes UNWIND is causing n issue. To get the set of unique nodes, you could also try APOC

```
MATCH p = (a:Version {version_id: 16674850})-[:DEPENDS_ON*..12]->(b:Version)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ((b)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->())
RETURN apoc.coll.toSet(
         apoc.coll.flatten(
           COLLECT(nodes(p))
         )
       ) AS unique nodes
```

Comment: That's a good idea. It works and returns `1723`. It also is very fast - "Started streaming 1 records after 1 ms and completed after 846 ms." However if I change the `11` to `12` the query runs forever, again.

Comment: Can you get the number of paths? So instead of UNWIND do a RETURN count (p)

Comment: That returns `59161`.

Comment: @zemirco I added some elements to my answer above. If you have about 60k paths, you would have max 60k*12 nodes returned. that number probably includes a lot of duplicates.

Comment: I edited the question and uploaded my data set. It's exactly the same data I currently use in my database. Maybe that helps reproducing my problem. I didn't really make any progress. Your suggestions are great. I'm pretty sure we're close to a solution.

Comment: I got `apoc` running and tried your last query. Unfortunately it returns an error `Invalid input 'nodes': expected ... `